# Fedora GRUB - How to remove unused entries?

Tags: fedora, grub2

**Problem**:

I used Fedora for some time and it would start in a usual way.

But recently, it started to display this screen:

[image: GRUB]

And it would display it **only after reboot**. If I however just turn on PC, it would load and stuck in this screen:

[image: GNOME Display Manager]

After reboot, I select `Fedora (5.0.17-300.fc30.x86_64) 30 (Thirty)` and it works.

**Question**:

*What are these other choices displayed and how can I remove the ones that are invalid ?*

---

EDIT:

**Solution**:
I managed to remove old kernels by running `dnf update` and following [this article](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/delete-remove-old-kernels-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) .

Comment: Old kernels, they're not invalid. Use `dnf` to remove those packages

Comment: Can you tell what how would I remove with with `dnf` ? What package should I remove ?

Comment: `rpm -qa kernel-\*` and then see which is the oldest. Remove these using `dnf remove kernel-xxxx`

Comment: Thank you both. I managed to remove it with `dnf update` and following this article https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/delete-remove-old-kernels-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/